# Cannot access to mysql container from another container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I use docker compose to run mysql and api server. Once api server is on it use connect to mysql, but I always got a access denied. I have add sql to grant permission but it still not work. Please someone help me.

Error

```
2018-05-03T05:48:45.868146Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'mysql'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  mysql:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile-mysql
    image: test_mysql:ci-label
    container_name: test-mysql-ci-label
    labels:
      - "CI-TEST=ci-label"
    networks:
      - ci-network
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  license:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    image: test_license:ci-label
    container_name: test-license-ci-label
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=dockertest
      - PORT=9502
    labels:
      - "CI-TEST=ci-label"
    networks:
      - ci-network
    ports:
      - "9502:9502"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    privileged: true

networks:
  ci-network:
    labels:
      - "CI-TEST=ci-label"
    name: ci-network
```

Here is my Dockerfile-mysql

```
FROM mysql:5.7
LABEL CI-TEST="ci-label"
ENV MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    MYSQL_USER=mysql \
    MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
COPY init.sql docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01.sql
```

Here is init.sql

```
-- Create database.
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `license` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
-- Create new user.
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON license.* TO 'mysql'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON license.* TO 'mysql'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Have you changed the password?

Comment: @hichamx You mean user or root?

Comment: Have you changed the password of user mysql? and can you connect to the database from within the mysql container?

Comment: Yes, I set env MYSQL_PASSWORD=test, I can use gui tool to connect to mysql. But another container cannot connect to mysql.

Comment: the user mysql has privileges only on license, so to connect to this specific schema you have to use something like : `mysql -u mysql -ptest -h 172.18.0.3 license`

Comment: @hichamx If I add this to init.sql, it will the same ?
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON license.* TO 'mysql'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';`

Comment: did my command above work? this grant command is already in your init.sql script

Comment: My workflow is on a single docker-compose. I am not sure when to operate your command. mysql and api server will start together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170277/discussion-between-hichamx-and-rukeith).